# Setting CanCan ability.rs model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I successfully made login system with Devise and CanCan, and I have 3 types of users. Admin, internal and global users. I created Controllers and index actions: Admin, Cpanel, Report and State, and I want to restrict access to this controllers for some users.

**Admin user** should have privilegies to access: Reports(all), State (read), Admin (all)

**Global user** should have privilegies to access: Reports(only read), State(read), Cpanel(all)

**Internal user** should have privilegies to access: Reports(all), State (read)

**And I tried to do this with following code in ability.rs**:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, [Report, Admin]
      can :read, State
    elsif user.role? :global_user
      can :read, [Report, State]
      can :manage, Cpanel
    elsif user.role? :internal_user
      can :manage, Report
      can :read, State     
    end
   end
end
```

At this time I have only index actions in this controllers, and when I login to app with internal user I CAN access to /admin for example, and that is not behavior that I want. I want to restrict access to all controllers  instead of controllers listed in ability.rb class.

[**Source code** is here](http://cl.ly/2E292R2m2B0X141q3C0S)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were going to prevent access to an entire controller, I would make a before filter that redirects the user to an access denied page if he does not have the admin role.  Might look something like:

```
def check_permissions
 raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless @current_user.role?(:admin)
end
```

If I just wanted to prevent access to update and create, for example, I would do:

```
def update
  raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless can?(:update,Thing)
  ...
end

def create
  raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless can?(:create,Thing)
  ...
end
```

You can handle the `CanCan::AccessDenied` exception in your application controller:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to no_access_path
  end
```

I have some pretty good posts about CanCan and Devise [here](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/) and [here](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/)

**UPDATE**
I use this method in my application controller to set my current user variable:

```
# Make the current user object available to views
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def get_user
    @current_user = session[:current_user]
  end
```

Comment: Why do I get undefined method `role?' for nil:NilClass?

Comment: And I have in User model method role?

Comment: That means you are calling the role? method on nil.  If you used my code above then your @current_user object is nil.  You need to make sure that is being set.  See my edit above for how I do it

Answer (score 2):

You need to add checks for the cancan authorization to your controllers.

This might be just adding a line like

```
authorize! :read, @state
```

to your state controller index action, and similarly for all the other index actions.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, in a state controller index action, you likely don't have @state, so the above wouldn't apply.  Possibly something like

```
authorize! :read, State
```

There is also a `load_and_authorize` method that you can use to combine authorization for multiple actions in a controller and reduce your code.  The `load_and_authorize` version is likely to look similar to

load_and_authorize_resource :state

and it should be before your actions.

You might want to look at this [railscast on cancan authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) for a complete basic setup (in rails2).

I suspect to clear up other problems, we might need to see some more code.  Try posting some of your controller code.

I haven't used this in rails3, but I assume most of it remains more or less similar.

Comment: And I can't access to /state nor with users that have permissions.

Comment: I added "authorize! :index, Admin" in Admin controller, index action.
Now, when I want to access to /admin loged as a global user, I get NameError in AdminController#index
uninitialized constant AdminController::Admin

Whole app is here:
http://cl.ly/2E292R2m2B0X141q3C0S

Comment: The :index should probably have still been :read - but I'll have a look at your whole controller and see if I spot anything.

Comment: Admin doesn't exist in your code.  The simple examples for cancan and all my code assume there's a model around that's being protected.  I don't really know how to use it in the absence of a model, but perhaps someone else can help.  You definitely need to do something in your controller, but I'm not quite sure what in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with

```
def check_permissions
 raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless current_user.role?(:admin)
end
```

but, note that I must to change `@current_user` to `current_user` (without @)

Thanks Tony